# How to pass additional variables to jqGrid formatter?

Tags: javascript, variables, jqgrid, formatter

I'm trying to create some kind of reusable formatter for jqGrid column,
I would like to create custom formatter where I'm able to pass additional data , something similar to this code:

```
function imageLinkFormatter(cellval,options,rowObject,icon,link_class,link_action){
     var img='<span class="ui-icon '+icon+' icon"><span/>';    
    var link='<a href="#'+link_action+'/id/'+rowObject.id+'" class="'+link_class+'" rel="'+rowObject.id+'">'+img+'</a>';
    return link;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not write any code like this or use jqGrid for modern projects :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's probably a misunderstanding. The interface of the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) is defined by jqGrid. To have additional parameters in the custom formatter you have to modify the source code of jqGrid.

The good news is that you don't really need to extend the *standard* custom formatter. Instead of that you want probably just share the code. So you can define the common code as the function like

```
function imageLinkFormatter(cellval, options, rowObject, icon, link_class, link_action) {
    var img = '<span class="ui-icon ' + icon + ' icon"><span/>';    
    var link = '<a href="#' + link_action + '/id/' + rowObject.id + '" class="' +
        link_class + '" rel="' + rowObject.id + '">' + img + '</a>';
    return link;
}
```

and call the function from the custom formatter of the different columns of the grid with additional parameters.

```
colModal: [
    {name: 'col1', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            return imageLinkFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject,
                'ui-icon-pencil', 'edit-link-class', 'Edit');
        }},
    {name: 'col2', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            return imageLinkFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject,
                'ui-icon-plus', 'add-link-class', 'Add');
        }},
    {name: 'col2', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            return imageLinkFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject,
                'ui-icon-trash', 'del-link-class', 'Delete');
        }},
    ...
]
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation,I thought that I have to extend custom formatter but this is perfect solution. Regards

Answer (score 8):

define formatoptions in the column definition

```js
colModal: [
    {name: 'col1', 
     formatter: imageLinkFormatter, 
     formatoptions: {
        icon: 'ui-icon-pencil', 
        link_class: 'edit-link-class', 
        action: 'Edit'
    }},
    {name: 'col2', formatter: imageLinkFormatter, formatoptions: {icon: 'ui-icon-plus', link_class: 'add-link-class', action: 'Add'}},
    {name: 'col3', formatter: imageLinkFormatter, formatoptions: {icon: 'ui-icon-trash', link_class: 'del-link-class', action: 'Add'}}
    ...
]
```

and then you can access it inside custom formatter

```js
function imageLinkFormatter(cellval, options, rowObject) {
    var img = '<span class="ui-icon ' + options.colModel.formatoptions.icon + ' icon"><span/>';
    var link = '<a href="#' + options.colModel.formatoptions.action + '/id/' + rowObject.id + '" class="' +
        options.colModel.formatoptions.link_class + '" rel="' + rowObject.id + '">' + img + '</a>';
    return link;
}
```